# Incomplete Type For a Variable - Though I Thought I Had Forward Declared Correctly?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Code compiled before I tried passing this class by reference into another class. You can ignore the fact I'm using QT.

I added all the files affected for completeness.

So I thought I had got the hang of forward declarations. Here is the error I'm getting which indicates the compiler isn't happy about a forward declaration:

```
error: field m_systemController has incomplete type
           SystemController m_systemController;
```

You can see the variable it freaks out over in the bottom .cpp:

This is the startup.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

namespace GUI{
    class SetupTab; //Should have my forward declarations in order
    class CbcRegistersTab;
    class DataTestTab;

    class MainView;

    class Settings;

    class SystemController;

    class DataTest;
    class SetupTabViewManager;


    class Startup : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Startup();
        void show() const ;

        ~Startup();
    private:
        SetupTab& m_setupTab;
        CbcRegistersTab& m_regTab;
        DataTestTab& m_dataTab;

        MainView& m_mainView;
        Settings* m_settings;

        SystemController& m_systemController;

        DataTest& m_dataTest; 

        SetupTabViewManager* m_setupTabVm;

        explicit Startup(const Startup& rhs) = delete;
        Startup& operator= (const Startup& rhs) = delete;
    };
}
```

This is the start of the startup.cpp:

```
#include "startup.h"
#include "View/setuptab.h"
#include "View/cbcregisterstab.h"
#include "View/datatesttab.h"
#include "View/mainview.h"
#include "Model/settings.h"
#include "Model/systemcontroller.h"
#include "Model/datatest.h"
#include "ViewMgr/setuptabviewmanager.h"
#include "provider.h" 

namespace GUI
{
    Startup::Startup() :
        QObject(nullptr),
        m_setupTab(*new SetupTab(nullptr)),
        m_regTab(*new CbcRegistersTab(nullptr)),
        m_dataTab(*new DataTestTab(nullptr)),

        m_mainView(*new MainView(nullptr,
                                 m_setupTab,
                                 m_regTab,
                                 m_dataTab)),

        m_systemController(*new SystemController(nullptr,
                                                 Provider::getSettingsAsSingleton())),

        m_dataTest(*new DataTest(nullptr,
                                m_systemController)), //so it's this part I'm having trouble with

        m_setupTabVm(new SetupTabViewManager(this,
                                             m_setupTab,
                                             m_systemController,
                                             Provider::getSettingsAsSingleton() ))
```

I then quite simply pass this value over into my datatest.h and tie it to a variable via reference:

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>

namespace GUI{

    class SystemController;

    class DataTest : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit DataTest(QObject *parent,
                          SystemController& sysCtrl);

        void runTest();

    private:

        SystemController m_systemController;

        explicit DataTest(const DataTest& rhs) = delete;
        DataTest& operator= (const DataTest& rhs) = delete;
    };

}
```

Then the top of the datatest.cpp:

```
#include "datatest.h"

#include "Model/systemcontroller.h"

namespace GUI
{
    DataTest::DataTest(QObject *parent,
                       SystemController& sysCtrl) :
        QObject(parent),
        m_systemController(sysCtrl) // FREAKS OUT HERE
    {
    }
```

Comment: You can make references or pointers to forward-declared types, but you cannot make fields of these types.

Comment: "Incomplete type" means that it *has* been declared, but *hasn't* been defined. It can only be used in limited ways without a definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `datatest.h` you have the following member variable

```
SystemController m_systemController;
```

Since the variable is an *instance* you need a full include, not just a forward declare.

You can only get away with a forward declaration if you only have pointers or references, like

```
SystemController* m_pSystemController;  // pointer
SystemController& m_rSystemController;  // reference
```

You can also use smart pointers with forward includes

```
std::unique_ptr<SystemController> m_pSystemController;
```

Comment: Thanks, nicely explained too